# When should i remove livedata observer on android?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I am observing a list in firestore using `LiveData` . This observations is dependent on another authentication `LiveData`.

Should i remove the old `LiveData` observer before creating the new one? What will happen if i don't?

Currently i am removing the observer using next code but i can simplify it greatly if i won't need to since i do the same all over my code

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
...

//Authentication observer which is the ItemAuto dependent
viewModel.auth.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {auth ->
            updateUserItemAutoLiveData(auth)
        })
}


private fun updateUserItemAutoLiveData(auth: Auth) {
        if (!auth.uid.isNullOrEmpty()) {

            removeUserItemAutoObservers()

            itemAutoLiveDate = viewModel.getUserItemAutoLiveData(auth.uid)

            itemAutoLiveDate!!.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                if (it != null) {
                    if (it.data != null) {
                        itemAutoCompleteAdapter.submitItemAuto(it)
                    } 
                }
            })

        } else {
            removeUserItemAutoObservers()
        }
    }

private fun removeUserItemAutoObservers() {
    if (itemAutoLiveDate != null && itemAutoLiveDate!!.hasObservers()) {
        itemAutoLiveDate!!.removeObservers(this)
    }
}
```

ps: i am using [Doug Stevenson tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXc4adLMDqk) which is great!

Comment: I think unless you `observeForever()` that's okay if you don't explicitly remove observer. library itself takes care this thing for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using `observe` method, `LiveData` will be automatically cleared in onDestroy state.

> Observers are bound to Lifecycle objects and clean up after themselves
> when their associated lifecycle is destroyed.

More information can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#the_advantages_of_using_livedata)

You need to remove livedata manually only if you use `observeForever` method. The reason why you need to remove it manually is because when you use `observeForever` method, you don't specify the lifecycle of it.